# How to to increase the baud rate of data transfer in the 8051?

Tags: microcontroller

In 8051 serial port programming transfers and receives data serially at many different baud rates, But how to increase the baud rate of data transfer in the 8051?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the Serial Port Baud Rate

Once the Serial Port Mode has been configured,  the program must configure the serial ports baud rate. This only applies to Serial Port modes 1 and 3. The Baud Rate is determined based on the oscillators frequency when in mode 0 and 2. In mode 0, the baud rate is always the oscillator frequency divided by 12. This means if youre crystal is 11.059Mhz, mode 0 baud rate will always be 921,583 baud. In mode 2 the baud rate is always the oscillator frequency divided by 64, so a 11.059Mhz crystal speed will yield a baud rate of 172,797.

In modes 1 and 3, the baud rate is determined by how frequently timer 1 overflows. The more frequently timer 1 overflows, the higher the baud rate. There are many ways one can cause timer 1 to overflow at a rate that determines a baud rate, but the most common method is to put timer 1 in 8-bit auto-reload mode (timer mode 2) and set a reload value (TH1) that causes Timer 1 to overflow at a frequency appropriate to generate a baud rate.

To determine the value that must be placed in TH1 to generate a given baud rate, we may use the following equation (assuming PCON.7 is clear).

```
TH1 = 256 - ((Crystal / 384) / Baud)
```

If PCON.7 is set then the baud rate is effectively doubled, thus the equation becomes:

```
TH1 = 256 - ((Crystal / 192) / Baud)
```

http://www.8052.com/tutser.phtml